# Using Ninject, how would I use the object currently in scope to determine if it's still in scope?

Tags: ninject

I have a scenario where an object should be reused by multiple concurrent web requests as long as a method on it returns true. The object in question is thread-safe.

So I need the object that is currently in scope to determine if it's still in scope. What would be the best way to accomplish this with Ninject?

While probably not needed to answer this question, the goal is to to reuse a Lucene IndexSearcher / IndexReader while the underlying index has not been changed. The Reader has a method IsCurrent that returns false if the index was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, You can define your own scope object. As long as the scope object is alive and not changed ninject will return the same instance of the binded type. The custom scope would need to check whether IsCurrent returns false. You can have a look on how to implement custom scope in 
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/tree/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope. Be aware that you have to take care not to create objects which will never be released for GC when you develop your own scope!

Answer (score 0):

In order to me the best to achieve what you want is to use a provider:

```
Bind<ILuceneIndex>().ToProvider(new LuceneIndexProvider());
```

and apply your logic of re-creation inside the provider.

Comment: If I understand correctly this would mean that the code I write in the provider would be responsible for keeping the current instance around somewhere? I was hoping it were possible to handle this with InScope in some way and have Ninject manage the rest.

Comment: @MichielRutting I know mine is probably not an elegant solution, I thought about doing something with .When() but I'm getting stuck because I fear to create some recursive lookup, didb't try anyway

Comment: Yes, the recursive nature of it is what makes me wonder. It feels like some weird chicken and egg problem :) I was basically going to write all the logic that would be in the provider, but wondered if there was something in Ninject's infrastructure that could save me some work.